# how to rotate a wheel in java without using swing?

Tags: java

I'm working on a java applet where i want move or rotate a wheel..so I take a circle and 3 lines which are placed at 60 degrees to each other on the circle...and the length of the lines are the diameter of the circle..

So I use a Line constructor which has initial positions of the lines and a degree with respect to x-axis i.e. after a certain time (here 1sec) it will rotate 5 degree.

This code works fine for line1, which is horizontal to x-axis..but cant work for line2 and line3..need some suggestion

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Line
    {
        int x1, x2, y1, y2, xChange=0, yChange=0; 
        double degree; 
        Line(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, double degree) 
        {
            this.x1=x1;
            this.y1=y1;
            this.x2=x2;
            this.y2=y2;
            this.degree=degree;
        }

        public void rotate(float radius)    
        {
        degree+=5;  
        double rads = Math.toRadians(degree); 

        x1+=5; 
        x2+=5;

        if(degree==0)
            degree=360;

        xChange=(int) (radius - ((Math.cos(rads)) * radius)); 
        yChange=(int) ((Math.sin(rads)) * radius);

        }
    }

public class Wheeler extends Applet implements Runnable
{
    Thread t1;
    int xCircle=40, yCircle=100, diameter=100;
    Line line1, line2, line3;
    int degree;
    float radius=diameter/2;

    public void init()   
    {
    xCircle=40; yCircle=100; diameter=100;
    line1=new Line(xCircle, yCircle+(diameter/2), xCircle+diameter, yCircle+(diameter/2), 0);
    line2=new Line(xCircle+(int) (radius - ((Math.cos(Math.toRadians(60)) * radius))), yCircle+(diameter/2)+(int) ((Math.sin(Math.toRadians(60)) * radius)), xCircle+diameter-(int) (radius - ((Math.cos(Math.toRadians(60)) * radius))), yCircle+(diameter/2)-(int) ((Math.sin(Math.toRadians(60)) * radius)), 60);    
    line3=new Line(xCircle+(int) (radius - ((Math.cos(Math.toRadians(120)) * radius))), yCircle+(diameter/2)+(int) ((Math.sin(Math.toRadians(120)) * radius)), xCircle+diameter-(int) (radius - ((Math.cos(Math.toRadians(120)) * radius))), yCircle+(diameter/2)-(int) ((Math.sin(Math.toRadians(120)) * radius)), 120);
    t1 = new Thread(this);
    t1.start();
    }

    public void run ()
    {
        while(true)                     
        {
            try
            {
                repaint();               
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                line1.rotate(radius);
                line2.rotate(radius);
                line3.rotate(radius);
                xCircle+=5;
                if(xCircle==1000)
                {
                    xCircle=40;
                    line1.x1=xCircle;
                    line1.x2=xCircle+diameter;
                    line2.x1=xCircle+(int) (radius - ((Math.cos(Math.toRadians(60))) * radius));
                    line2.x2=xCircle+diameter-(int) (radius - ((Math.cos(Math.toRadians(60)) * radius)));
                    line3.x1=xCircle+(int) (radius - ((Math.cos(Math.toRadians(120)) * radius)));
                    line3.x2=xCircle+diameter-(int) (radius - ((Math.cos(Math.toRadians(120)) * radius)));
                }
            }
             catch(InterruptedException e) {} 
        }

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) 
    {
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.drawOval(xCircle, yCircle, diameter, diameter);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawLine(line1.x1+line1.xChange, line1.y1-line1.yChange, line1.x2-line1.xChange, line1.y2+line1.yChange);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawLine(line2.x1+line2.xChange, line2.y1-line2.yChange, line2.x2-line2.xChange, line2.y2+line2.yChange);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawLine(line3.x1+line3.xChange, line3.y1-line3.yChange, line3.x2-line3.xChange, line3.y2+line3.yChange);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just for the record: you understand that Applets are dead technology? Chrome has abandoned Java; and Java9 will also drop Applets. So - why do spent your time building a saddle for a ... dead horse?

Comment: And for your actual question: you verified (using a debugger or printouts) that your "lines" all have valid coordinates? In other words: you are sure that "all the math" you are using leads to correct results?